# Logback.xml Same Package Log Different Level

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I am using Slf4 for logging. I want to create two log file for the same package. INFO level log and DEBUG level log. I tried to implement like that

```
enter code here
<!-- User Friendly Application Logs -->
<logger name="com.example.app" level="INFO" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<!-- Debug Application Log Level -->
<logger name="com.example.app" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG-FILE" />
</logger>

<!-- Console Root Log Level -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```

I am missing a point because, I can see DEBUG level for all files. When I remove logger for debug, I never see the debug log in the ref="FILE".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, I believe you want the DEBUG level in DEBUG-FILE, and only the INFO level in FILE.

Try putting the DEBUG level **above** the INFO level logs in your Logback.xml, and adding `additivity="false"` in DEBUG level. You may remove `additivity="true"` in INFO level.

```
<!-- Debug Application Log Level -->
<logger name="com.example.app" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUG-FILE" />
</logger>

<!-- User Friendly Application Logs -->
<logger name="com.example.app" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<!-- Console Root Log Level -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```